# Flutter black screen when pushing a route in iOS

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I'm on Splash screen and it works fine and after 4 seconds, I'm jumping to the login screen and instead of displaying the login screen, it shows me a black screen with nothing on it.
I'm jumping to the Login screen with

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
```

Can Anyone tell me where am I going wrong? I've tried various methods like using a WillPopScope() widget on both routes (Splash and login),  Changing the route names,

Its working very well on Android but not on iOS and this is kind of strange.
My code for Login Page is

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 this._context = context;
 return new GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
    _dismissKeyboard(_context);
   },
   child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldState,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: !isLoading
          ? new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Hero(
                        tag: "pricelogo",
                        child: new Container(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                        )),
                    Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration:
                          BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlue[50]),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: new Container(
                            child: new ImageIcon(
                              new AssetImage("assets/user.png"),
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Email',
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        decoration:
                            BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlue[50]),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 20.0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                        child: new TextField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            icon: new Container(
                                child: new ImageIcon(
                              new AssetImage("assets/password.png"),
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            )),
                            hintText: 'Password',
                            hintStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                        )),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 45.0),
                      child: Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.blue,
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: 300.0,
                          height: 50.0,
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (areFieldsValid()) {
                              if (_connectionStatus ==
                                      ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
                                  _connectionStatus ==
                                      ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
                                _makeLoginApiCall();
                              } else {
                                scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                    new SnackBar(
                                        content: new Text(
                                            "Please check your internet connection and try again")));
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text('Login',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      child: Text("or sign in with:"),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          isFacebookSignInEnabled
                              ? Image(
                                  image: AssetImage("assets/facebook.png"),
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  width: 50.0,
                                )
                              : Container(),
                          Container(
                            width: isGoogleSignInEnabled ? 40.0 : 0.0,
                          ),
                          isGoogleSignInEnabled
                              ? Image(
                                  image: AssetImage("assets/google.png"),
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  width: 50.0,
                                )
                              : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Don't have an account?",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Signup()));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "  Signup",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ForgotPassword()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          : Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 4.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: put the code of your splashscreen

Comment: I can navigate to any other screen from splash screen but not on the login screen so I guess there’s no issue in the splash, anyways I’ll post the code for splash.